# MongoDB migration

Tags: mongodb, migration, export, ubuntu-16.04

Hello I have an ubuntu 14.04 server that is running mongodb 2.4.14. I need to move the mongo instance to a new server. I have installed mongo 3.4.2 on the new server and need to move the databases over. I am pretty new with mongo. I have 2 databases that are pretty big but when I do a mongo dump the file is nowhere near the site of the databases that mongo is showing.I cannot figure out how to get mongoexport to work. What would be the best way to move those databases? If possible can we just export the data from mongo and then import it?

Comment: mongodump -db game_stats --out /root is what im am using to export the database.

Comment: onnected to: 127.0.0.1
Fri Feb 17 11:13:02.582 DATABASE: game_stats  to  /root/game_stats
error: boost::filesystem::create_directory: Permission denied: "/root/game_stats"
voonami@d7-app-001:~$ sudo mongodump -db game_stats --out /root
connected to: 127.0.0.1
Fri Feb 17 11:13:14.661 DATABASE: game_stats  to  /root/game_stats
Fri Feb 17 11:13:14.729  game_stats.system.indexes to /root/game_stats/system.indexes.bson
Fri Feb 17 11:13:14.732    1 objects
Fri Feb 17 11:13:14.732  game_stats.game_stats to /root/game_stats/game_stats.bson

Comment: Fri Feb 17 11:13:17.202   Collection File Writing Progress: 1400/3583 39% (objects)
Fri Feb 17 11:13:19.295    3583 objects
Fri Feb 17 11:13:19.295  Metadata for game_stats.game_stats to /root/game_stats/game_stats.metadata.json

Comment: mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.14
connecting to: test
> show dbs
bbgame 0.203125GB
bsgame 0.203125GB
fbgame 0.203125GB
game_stats 7.9501953125GB
instagram 0.203125GB
local 0.078125GB
social 0.953125GB
sogame 0.203125GB
test 0.203125GB
twitter 0.203125GB
vbgame 0.203125GB

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 root root 255M Feb 17 11:13 game_stats.bson
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  103 Feb 17 11:13 game_stats.metadata.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   76 Feb 17 11:13 system.indexes.bson

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to give more information on your issue with mongodump and what mongodump parameters you were using.

Since you are doing a migration, you'll want to use mongodump and not mongoexport. mongoexport only outputs a JSON/CSV format of a collection. Because of this, mongoexport cannot retain certain datatypes that exist in BSON and thus MongoDB does not suggest that anyone uses mongoexport for full backups; [this consideration is listed on mongo's site](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#considerations).

`mongodump` will be able to accurately create a backup of your database/collection that `mongorestore` will be able to restore that dump to your new server.

If you haven't already, check out [Back Up and Restore with MongoDB Tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/)

Comment: I added that information to my post please review and let me know what I am missing the database is 7.9 GB but the export is only 200 MB for whatever reason.

Comment: @compprog254 you ran the command `mongodump -db game_stats --out /root` which will dump the `game_stats` database. According to your `show dbs`, `game_stats` is listed as: `0.203125GB game_stats` which is around 200MB. Did you mean to dump the `instagram` database which is ~7.9GB (`7.9501953125GB instagram`)?

Comment: @compprog254 did this help?

Comment: you read that wrong the size is after the database name not before @sstrickland

Comment: @compprog254 sorry about that. What are the results for db.stats() and db.game_stats.stats()